# IntentBuilder(Context,ComponentName) has private access in IntentBuilder

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-11, android-implicit-intent

The following is the error I get when I try running the application

```
error: constructor IntentBuilder in class IntentBuilder cannot be applied to given types;
                new ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
                ^
  required: Context,ComponentName
  found: Context
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

within the Anonymous new View.OnClickListener(), onClick() method at the first line of `new ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(...)`.

When I surf above that line which have red curly underline, Android Studio shows the following message:

`'IntentBuilder(android.content.Context, android.content.ComponentName)' has private access in 'androidx.core.app.ShareCompat.IntentBuilder'`

I am working on Android Version `API 30: Andorid 11.0 (R)`.

```
package com.example.implicitintents;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.core.app.ShareCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context = this;
    private Button openShareBtn;
    private EditText shareEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

        openShareBtn = findViewById(R.id.open_share_button);
        shareEditText = findViewById(R.id.share_edittext);

        openShareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String txt = shareEditText.getText().toString();
                String mimeType = "text/plain";
                new ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
                        .setType(mimeType)
                        .setChooserTitle("Share this text with: ")
                        .setText(txt)
                        .startChooser();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the `AndroidManifest.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.implicitintents">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ImplicitIntents">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

Below is the `build.gradle (Module: Implicit_Intents:app)` content:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.implicitintents"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Can you please help me out here, I am stuck with this error?

Thank you. If more information is required please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro Tip: Android in open source. If you run into this kind of issue, you can jump to the class definition and see what's wrong.

In this case, by looking at the `ShareCompat` source, you find that while the constructor is private, there is a [from](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ShareCompat.IntentBuilder#from(android.app.Activity)) static builder method.

Strangely, this is marked as deprecated in the documentation, so it seems like a documentation bug:

Constructors don't work even though the documentation says to use it:

[image]

The `from` static constructor is available.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the public constructor:

```
new ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)
                    .setType(mimeType)
                    .setChooserTitle("Share this text with:")
                    .setText(txt)
                    .startChooser();
```

Shown here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ShareCompat.IntentBuilder#public-constructors

---

You could also get the context straight off the View instead of storing it as a field:

```
new ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(v.getContext())
                    .setType(mimeType)
                    .setChooserTitle("Share this text with:")
                    .setText(txt)
                    .startChooser();
```

Comment: new ShareCompat.IntentBuilder(context)

  required: Context,ComponentName
  found: Context
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: It gives me the following error as shown on the above comment

Comment: what version of AndroidX are you on? Check if there is an update

Comment: I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3. And I checked for updates, there is none.

Comment: Not Android Studio. in your `build.gradle` check the version of the androidx dependency, I think its `androidx.core` but I am not certain

Comment: I have updated my question by adding build.gradle file content

Comment: This is the correct answer - if you're still having issues, update your question with your new code (using the single-argument constructor) and the _exact_ error you're still getting.

Comment: @dominicoder I have updated the question with single argument constructor and the respective error I get.

Comment: when all else fails, try: File > Invalidate Caches & Restart

Comment: The problem is likely a mix of using the platform classes, and the replacement AndroidX classes. You could try deleting all your imports, and reimport them one by one, noticing when you have a choice of two (androix or regular) which one you choose

Comment: @Blundell I tried both methods as you specified. But to no result its still there.